# A second UITableView populated following the choice of another UITableView on one UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know the question of two `UITableViews` on one `UIViewController` is a common one but I have not found a solution to one being dependant on the choice of another.

I have a `UIViewController` with two `UITableViews`. Table 1 is populated from a CoreData entity with a distinct list of names. When I choose a name from Table 1 I would like Table 2 to be populated with all records related to that person.

[image]

The following code works in that Table 1 is populated correctly. However when I choose a name from Table 1 the array based on the selection (which is correct) goes into Table 1 and not Table 2.

I also realise that were a second name to be chosen from Table 1 it will not quite work since it does not distinguish which table has been chosen. Any suggestions here welcome too. I have read that tagging tables is the answer but I have had little success.

Many thanks in advance.

Can anyone help me

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
tableLoad=1;

[tableView setDelegate: self];
[tableView setDataSource: self];

.... code for populating teacherNames with names from Core data

[self.tableView reloadData];
}

-(void) loadSecondTable;
{
[observationTableView setDelegate: self];
[observationTableView setDataSource: self];
tableLoad=2;
[self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if (tableLoad==1)
{
return self.teacherNames.count;
}
else
{
return self.observationNames.count;
}
}

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (tableLoad == 1)
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"teacherCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
NSString *currentList = [[self.teacherNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"obsTeacherName"];
cell.textLabel.text = currentList;
return cell;
}
else
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"observationCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
Observations *currentList = [self.observationNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Class %@ - %@ - %@", currentList.obsClassName, currentList.obsDate, currentList.obsDateTimeStart];
return cell;
}
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 if(tableLoad==1)
 {
 teacherChosenFromTable = [[self.teacherNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"obsTeacherName"];

 NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Observations"];
 fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"obsTeacherName" ascending:YES]];
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"obsTeacherName == '%@'", teacherChosenFromTable]];
 [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
 NSError *error = nil;

 self.observationNames = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
 [self loadSecondTable];
 }

 else

 {

 .... load next view based on selection of Table 2

 }
}
```

Comment: In loadSecondTable method, you called "[self.tableView reloadData];"
Change it to "[observationTableView reloadData];" and have another try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't control the redrawing of tableViews when you scroll it the IOS framework call the DataSource when they need it. The algorithme to populate the data must take into account that. You need to verify which tableView call the delegate.

Try this :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [tableView setDelegate: self];
    [tableView setDataSource: self];

    [observationTableView setDelegate: self];
    [observationTableView setDataSource: self];


    .... code for populating teacherNames with names from Core data

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

//-(void) loadSecondTable;
//{
//  [observationTableView setDelegate: self];
//  [observationTableView setDataSource: self];
//  [self.tableView reloadData];
//}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

//Caution you name your first tableView tableview and mask the parameter methode you need to rename it
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)p_TableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if (p_tableView == tableView )
    {
        return self.teacherNames.count;
    }
    else
    {
        return self.observationNames.count;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)p_TableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (p_TableView == tableView )
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"teacherCell";   
        UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        NSString *currentList = [[self.teacherNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"obsTeacherName"];
        cell.textLabel.text = currentList;
        return cell;
    }
    else
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"observationCell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        Observations *currentList = [self.observationNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Class %@ - %@ - %@", currentList.obsClassName, currentList.obsDate, currentList.obsDateTimeStart];
        return cell;
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)p_TableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (p_TableView == tableView )
    {
        teacherChosenFromTable = [[self.teacherNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"obsTeacherName"];

        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Observations"];
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"obsTeacherName" ascending:YES]];
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"obsTeacherName == '%@'", teacherChosenFromTable]];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
        NSError *error = nil;

        self.observationNames = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }

    else

    {

        .... load next view based on selection of Table 2

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I really appreciate the time you have put into this. I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do tagging. The methods are called on the same thread but there's no way in general to control the state of `tableLoad` correctly. All datasource methods have a tableView as an argument, compare the argument value with the values of linked outlets or variables where you should save the references to your table views after they are initialized.

Distinguish the table view where the cell is selected in the same way.